# Dual Citizenship and Brexit

Tags: dual-citizenship, denmark, brexit

I left Britain over 20 years ago after being homeless as a teenager. While living on the streets, I got involved in teenage criminality, was arrested and was sentenced for it. That with other harsh family situations made me leave England to start again elsewhere in Europe.

Now I live in Denmark and have not been involved in any criminal activities. I have worked and earned a living, until I became too sick to work and was put on medication.

Will my past criminal record affect application to be Danish citizen?

If it will, how can my name be cleared in UK online, since my health cannot allow me to travel there personally?

I ask since the form for application to be citizen indicates that one should mention any jail sentences or crimes for which one is yet to be sentenced in home country. I am English, but after Brexit, I must apply for citizenship in Denmark. Otherwise my wife (who is a foreigner from outside EU) and I risk our marriage, property, benefits and her job if the Brexit rules mean I must return to a homeless state in the UK. Just to mention that I have children here with my ex-wife.

Comment: A 20 year old sentence may very well be relevant if you apply for Danish citizenship. What was your sentence, and in case of imprisonment, when were you released? Since when do you live in Denmark? Do you currently provide for yourself, or do you rely on public welfare?

Comment: I don't know about naturalization in Denmark, but even if you cannot do that there's a good chance that your right of permanent residence will survive the UK's departure from the EU. You should establish and document your right of permanent residence if you have not done so already.

Comment: Your situation cannot be assessed unless you answer the questions in my first comment. Voting to close as unclear until you do so.